# Why stomp can't run in apache?

Tags: php, apache, stomp, selinux

- **Brief Intro**

I'm now using stomp to connect with ActiveMQ based on a PHP site running on apache server.
The Stomp can run in bash but can't run in apache.

- **Preparation**

I install stomp by

```
pecl install stomp
```

and modify the php.ini with

```
extension=stomp.so
```

I have a 'index.php' like this:

```
<?php
echo 'runing-';
/* connection */
try {
    $stomp = new Stomp('tcp://localhost:61613');
    echo 'connecting-';
} catch(StompException $e) {
    die('Error! Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
$stomp->send('/queue/test', 'Hello from PHP');
echo 'finished.';
/* close connection */
unset($stomp);
?>
```

- **Start Working**

Firstly, I run with

```
$ php index.php
```

And it echo as my expectation:

```
$ php index.php
runing-connecting-finished.
```

Then I open it in browser:

```
http://localhost/index.php
```

It reports

```
runing-Error! Connection failed: Unable to connect to localhost:61613
```

- **Question**

I've searching resolution for this error all day...
I guess apache block the request from stomp since it runs successfully in bash.

What should I do to fix this bug?

Thanks really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

an experienced colleague called Justin get things done!
Though not really understand this situation,
I post my solution here:

Firstly, I run **sestatus**:

```
$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

Justin told me to change settings in **/etc/sysconfig/selinux** to

```
SELINUX=permissive
```

Then I restart and run **sestatus** again:

```
$ sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /selinux
Current mode:                   permissive
Mode from config file:          permissive
Policy version:                 24
Policy from config file:        targeted
```

Finally things work!

Linux stuff still seems a little magical for me.
Who knows something about this please give an explanation about this.

Thanks a lot.